# Alternative proof for continuity of matrix inversion

Tags: matrices, continuity, alternative-proof

I am to show that

$\mathrm{inv}: \mathrm{GL}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathrm{GL}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}); A \mapsto A^{-1}$

is a continuous function. I have shown this by showing that the deteriminant is continuous, and that forming the adjunct is continuous, in which case one can apply the formula

$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\mathrm{det}(A)}\mathrm{adj}(A)$.

This is all fine, but I would love to see a more intuitive proof that doesn’t simply rely on showing that some formula is composed of continuous functions. I tried finding some sort of relation between the operator norms of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ but couldn’t find anything that holds in the general case. For example, if something along the lines of

$\min_{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}}{(Ax)} \times \max_{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}}{(A^{-1}x)} = 1$

were true, one could construct an epsilon-delta proof via that. However, the above expression while inutive, appears to be false (it seems to hold only if the chosen x happen to be eigenvectors unless my attempts to verify it in mathematica were somehow wrong). Does anyone know of a more intuitive proof of the statement than the one I outlined above?

Comment: Note that the det proof only works for finite dimensional operators i.e. matrices. For the general proof that works in any Banach algebra, see Yves Daoust's answer.

Comment: Oh, yea, we’re in R^n, not in an infinite-dimensional space.

Comment: If you show that row operations are continuous on $GL_{n\times n}$, the Gauss-Jordan algorithm immediately implies that inversion is a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: @user37208 Are you sure that is valid? By changing the values of A, gaussian elimination might make use of different operations, in which case I'm not sure continuity can be concluded without any problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $A_0\in GL({\mathbb R}^n)$ be given, and put $${1\over\|A_0^{-1}\|}=:\alpha>0\ .$$
It follows that for all  $x$ we have
$$|x|=|A_0^{-1}A_0 x|\leq{1\over\alpha}|A_0 x|$$
and therefore $|A_0x|\geq\alpha|x|$. Assume that $\|A-A_0\|<{\alpha\over2}$. Then
$$|Ax|\geq|A_0x|-|(A-A_0)x|\geq{\alpha\over 2}|x|\ ,$$
hence such an $A$ is again regular and has an inverse $A^{-1}$ of norm $\leq{2\over\alpha}$. From
$$A^{-1}-A_0^{-1}=A^{-1}(A_0-A)A_0^{-1}$$
we now deduce
$$\|A^{-1}-A_0^{-1}\|\leq\|A^{-1}\|\>\|A_0-A\|\>\|A_0^{-1}\|\leq{2\over\alpha^2}\|A-A_0\|\ .$$
This shows that ${\rm inv}$ is even Lipschitz continuous at $A_0$.

Comment: I'm struggling to follow one part of this argument - the claim that $\|A^{-1}\|\le \frac{2}{\alpha}$. From $|Ax| \ge \frac{\alpha}{2}|x|$ it is clear that (assuming $\|\cdot\|$ is an operator norm), $\|A\|\ge \frac{\alpha}{2}$, but I can't see how to get from this to $\|A^{-1}\|\le \frac{2}{\alpha}$. Any hint would be much appreciated! (Just the norm inequality -  I can see that this implies the inverse exists).

Comment: @AlexHodges: Given an arbitrary $y$, let $x:=A^{-1}y$ in $|Ax|\geq{2\over\alpha}|x|$.

Comment: Ah, right - that's super neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**

For a small matrix $\delta$ (such that $\|A^{-1}\delta\|<1$), $$(A+\delta)^{-1}=(A(I+A^{-1}\delta))^{-1}=(I+A^{-1}\delta)^{-1}A^{-1}=(I-A^{-1}\delta+(A^{-1}\delta)^2-\cdots)A^{-1}$$ (the series can be made to converge) so that

$$\|(A+\delta)^{-1}-A^{-1}\|\le\|A^{-1}\|^2\,\|I-A^{-1}\delta+\cdots\|\,\|\delta\|$$

is small as well.

Answer (score 5):

In finite dimension, also works the implicit function theorem. The matrix product $(X,Y)\longmapsto XY$ is bilinear and continuous, so $C^1$. The inverse is given by the equation $XA = I$ Check that
$$\frac{\partial(XA - I)}{\partial A}$$
is inversible and this proves that $A\longmapsto X = A^{-1}$ is $C^1$.